# angularjs device back button not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, addeventlistener

I am trying to create dialog when device back button clicked, searched internet and came up with the coding.
1.when i use the below coding, Clicking back button shows dialog ok and cancel when i click ok:the app closes.
2. when i click cancel: the app closes.

```js
app.run(['$rootScope','$mdDialog','$cordovaDialogs', function($rootScope, $mdDialog, $cordovaDialogs) {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    console.log("deviceready");
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown,false);
      function onBackKeyDown() {
        if(confirm("Are You sure You wanna Exit?")){
          console.log("true");
          navigator.app.exitApp();
        }else{
    return false;
    }
    }
  },false);
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
    $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
  });
}]);
```

Please look into the above coding, i am doing anything wrong.. ? I just need to show confirm dialog inside device ready.. And cancel must not end the app.. Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: Is it in `cordova` application ?

Comment: Angularjs Application

Comment: Read the reference material before you copy-paste things. `deviceready` and `backbutton` are `cordova` life-cycle events..

Comment: i have used ngCordova in my application..?

Comment: i have added my app to ionic, which has cordova. I have edited the above question please see and reply guys.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support guys, I have completed this issue by getting help from my mates.. Please see the code below.. :)

```js
app.run(['$rootScope','$location', function($rootScope,$location) {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    console.log("deviceready");
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
function onBackKeyDown(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($location.path() === "/login" || $location.path() === "/home") {
  var r=confirm("exit");
 if(r==true){
  console.log("not exit");
  navigator.app.exitApp();
 }else {
     navigator.app.goBack();
    }
}else {
    /* $ionicHistory.goBack(); */
 window.history.back();
    navigator.app.goBack();
}
}
}, 100);
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
    $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

sry, I have changed the code like this then also the same the app closes for both true and false of confirm..

```js
app.run(['$rootScope','$mdDialog','$cordovaDialogs', function($rootScope, $mdDialog, $cordovaDialogs) {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    console.log("deviceready");
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown,false);
      function onBackKeyDown() {
        if(confirm("Are You sure You wanna Exit?")){
          console.log("true");
          navigator.app.exitApp();
        }else{
          return false;
     }
    }
  },true);
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
    $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
  });
}]);
```