# Angular JS application device back button must have confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

I am doing an AngularJS mobile application which has some modules. I need to access the device's back button in my application, Dialog must have "OK" and "Cancel".

1. When "OK" is clicked, it must close the application.
2. When "Cancel" is clicked, it must close the dialog box or return false.

I have tried many methods, I can't get the result as expected. Please anyone suggest me to solve this issue. I like to finish this any way possible. Please look at my another question in Stack Overflow. I have given some coding which is used in this question.

[AngularJS device back button not working.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331734/angularjs-device-back-button-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support guys, I have completed this issue by getting help from my mates.. Please see the code below.. :)

```js
app.run(['$rootScope','$location', function($rootScope,$location) {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    console.log("deviceready");
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
function onBackKeyDown(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($location.path() === "/login" || $location.path() === "/home") {
  var r=confirm("exit");
 if(r==true){
  console.log("not exit");
  navigator.app.exitApp();
 }else {
     navigator.app.goBack();
    }
}else {
    /* $ionicHistory.goBack(); */
 window.history.back();
    navigator.app.goBack();
}
}
}, 100);
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
    $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use [$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/) and check if there is a navigation history among views (except the login page):

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (e) {
    if ($ionicHistory.backView() && $ionicHistory.backView().stateName != "login") {
        // history back except login page
        $ionicHistory.goBack();
    } else {
        var confirmPopup = $myPopup.confirm({
                cssClass: 'center-txt-popup',
                title: '<b>Closing app</b>',
                template: "Do you want to exit?"
            });
        confirmPopup.then(function (close) {
            if (close) {
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            }
        });
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}, 101); // 1 more priority than back button
```

Comment: With priority 101 the handler override the 'back to previous view ' default. Check ionic docs (link in the answer) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Use `SweetAlert` which is perfect for your situation!

But you need to import a JS file `sweet-alert.min.js`.

```
SweetAlert.swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "You want to go back!",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55", confirmButtonText: "OK",
                cancelButtonText: "CANCEL",
                closeOnConfirm: true,
                closeOnCancel: true
            }, function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
//you logic goes here
}
});
```

Hopefully this should help!

Comment: Thanks i will try and revert back vkrishna.. :)

Comment: Sweet alert dialog also coming only after app closing..??

Answer (score 0):

You can use ionic hardwareBackbutton as follow:

```
$ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (true) { // your check here
        $ionicPopup.confirm({
           title: 'System warning',
           template: 'are you sure you want to exit?'
        }).then(function(res) {
        if (res) {
            ionic.Platform.exitApp();
         }
        })
     }
});
```

Comment: I have already used this i am getting some error on onHardwareBackButton i think..

Comment: what error  ?? have you added $ionicPlatform in dependency?

Comment: app.run(['$rootScope','$cordovaDialogs','$ionicPlatform', function($rootScope, $cordovaDialogs,$ionicPlatform) { $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
*inside your code..}); 
   }]); the dialog box doesn't show this closes the application..

Comment: Try after adding event.preventDefault(); and event.stopPropagation(); in function

Comment: can you please say where i have to add the event.preventDefault(); and event.stopPropagation();

Comment: Used this coding but the app closes divyesh.... app.run(['$rootScope','$ionicPopup','$ionicPlatform', function($rootScope, $ionicPopup, $ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
   $ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(function() {
     event.preventDefault();
     event.stopPropagation(); *if(true) coding...
    }
 });
 });
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
    $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
  });
}]);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103184/discussion-between-om-bala-and-divyesh-savaliya).